# new domain not pointing to the right server

Tags: domain-name-system, apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

i recently bought a new domain and pointed it to another host. i decided to move to more powerful server so then the following day, I added an A record for my dedicated server 23.23.23.23 on my registrar. I have anotherdomain.com already running on this server.

```
A mysite.com 23.23.23.23 
A www.mysite.com 23.23.23.23 
A *.mysite.com 23.23.23.23
```

heres my apache2 conf inside sites-available

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName www.mysite.com
        ServerAlias mysite.com *.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
        <Directory />
                AllowOverride None
                Options FollowSymLinks
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/mysite>
                AllowOverride All
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

The problem is that when i navigate to mysite.com it takes me to the old host's page i was using yesterday and doesn't display the page on my dedicated server! It works on and off for past 24 hours.

When I wget mysite.com from other servers, it works fine. I ran checkdns.net and everything is fine!

whats going on ? how can i fix this ???

Comment: This kind of problem is difficult to look at if you don't provide the real domains and let us dig through the DNS entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description above, it sounds like this is probably down to dns server caching time.

The dns servers in use by (a) checkdns.net and (b) the servers you're wget'ing from, reflect the updated information. However, depending on TTL, this updated information may not be reflected elsewhere (where the DNS servers in use have the old information cached).

For more information, see the section under 'Caching Time' at the wikipedia article on DNS [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).

Comment: By the way - a temporary solution, if you want to be able to address your new server by its domain name in the meantime (and verify that your virtualhost config is correct): You could edit your hosts file (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file) to create an entry for your server's ip and FQDN.

Answer (score 2):

"Working on and off" points strongly at DNS caching being the culprit.  Check with your local caching resolvers (each of them, one by one) and examine the cached TTL and RR data.  That'll tell you either (a) which resolver needs a flush, or (b) how long you've got to wait.  If they're all in sync but things are still having problems, then give us the real domain and IP address(es) you want and people can investigate on their own.